max_text_length KivyMD
I came across max_text_length in the KivyMD docs but it isn't preventing input to be more than I specify. Instead, the font color changes to red when I enter more than the specified amount of 3 characters but still allows me to key in more than 3 characters.


The input_filter: 'int' line in the below KivyMD code won't allow anything other than an integer to be entered. This is the sort of thing I would like to have the max_text_length do by not allowing more than 3 digits to be entered. Is there something in KivyMD that will not allow more than 3 characters (integers in my case) to be entered into the input field? To add a layer of complexity to this, I actually need to be able to have exactly 3 digits be entered. In other words a min of 3 digits and a max of 3 digits. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
MDTextField:
            mode: "round"
            id: place
            input_filter: 'int'
            max_text_length: 3
            hint_text: "3 Digit Number"
            valign: 'center'
            icon_right: "apps"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 250
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}


I'm not sure if there is a way to set the textfield input to be exactly as 3 characters, in your case what I would do is use the on_text and on_text_validate events and create a function that trims the text always to the first three characters and another function give a warning to the user when tries to enter a less than 3 digits input, something like this will do the job:
MDTextField:
        id: my3digitstextfield
        mode: "outlined"
        multiline: False
        on_text: root.trim_textfield_input(self.text)
        on_text_validate: root.validate_3_digits_textfield(self.text)
        width: dp(250)

Then you create your functions that I think the names are self explanatory:
def trim_textfield_input(self, text2trim):
    if len(text2trim) > 3:
        self.ids.my3digitstextfield.text = text2trim[:3]

def validate_3_digits_textfield(self, text2validate):
    if len(text2validate) < 3:
        self.show_ok_dialog(f"[b]'{text2validate}'[/b] it's too short", "3 digits minimun required.")

def show_ok_dialog(self, dialogTitle, dialogText):

    self.optionokdialog = MDDialog(
        MDDialogHeadlineText(
            text=f"{dialogTitle}",
            halign="left",
        ),
        MDDialogSupportingText(
            text=f"{dialogText}",
            halign="left",
        ),
        MDDialogButtonContainer(
            MDWidget(),
            MDButton(
                MDButtonIcon(icon="check-bold"),
                MDButtonText(text="OK"),
                style="outlined",
                on_release=lambda _: self.optionokdialog.dismiss()
            ),
            spacing="8dp",   
        ),
        auto_dismiss=False
    )
    self.optionokdialog.open()

Finally, just make sure that your functions will be called at root. or self. or app. according to the case.

Thanks @josecr !
After thinking about it since last night, I came up with an answer to my own question that is doing what I want. I made a function that validates the length of the entry. This function is called by an on-press: in the Kivy file. I kept the input_filter: 'int' and max_text_length calls in the Kivy file. The max_text_length call is really just eye candy as it does not enforce the max length.
KivyMD MDTextField: code
MDTextField:
    mode: "round"
    id: number
    input_filter: 'int'
    max_text_length: 3
    hint_text: "3 Digit Number"
    valign: 'center'
    icon_right: "apps"
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 250
    font_size: 18
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

KivyMD MDRoundFlattButton: code
MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "submit your entry"
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
            on_press: app.entry_validate()

Python function code
def entry_validate(self):
    value = (self.root.get_screen('entry_screen').ids.number.text)
    while(True):
        if len(value) <3:
            print('Your entry is too short. Try again')
            break;
        elif len(value) >3:
            print('Your entry is too long. Try again')
            break;
        else:
            print('You entered: %s' % value)
            break;

The function goes and grabs the 'int' that was entered in the MDTextField: and validates the length of the 'int'.
I'm not sure this is the cleanest code, but it does what I need for now. I am going to replace the else: statement with a MySQL database entry instead of a print statement.
Something CRITICAL to this code working properly is that you have to remove the comma after the word "text" at the end of the value variable in your function call to get the int entered from the MDTextField. This comma denotes a tuple I beleive and we want a int. The tuple always gave a "Your entry is too short. Try again" response no matter the length of digits entered. As soon as I removed the comma at the end, it worked as expected. See below:
Incorrect
value = (self.root.get_screen('entry_screen').ids.number.text,)

Correct
value = (self.root.get_screen('entry_screen').ids.number.text)

